# Put Outlook rules into Exchange

Tags: exchange-2003

Almost embarrassed to ask as I am sure it is very simple...

How do I make Outlook message rules be server based rather than client, so that they will work on web access, Smartphone etc...

Using SBS2003/Exchange 2003/Outlook 2003

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Outlook/Exchange message rules are applied as *server-side* rules. They are evaluated even if Outlook is not running.

But there are certain rules that are always client-only – those involving some element from Outlook that does not exist on the Exchange Server.

There is a good article which explains [Server-based vs. Client-based rules](http://www.slipstick.com/rules/serverbased.htm).

Comment: That was the problem - it was looking at recipient address and hence is client side only - cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Another gotcha is that Exchange will process rules server-side until the *first* client-side rule, so you can mix them, but be careful, some experimentation can often change client-side rules to server-side.

My first rule is to permanently delete "very spammy" mail, but for some reason "permanently delete" is client side, but "move to deleted items" is not.